# Enviar Bundle entre dos aplicaciones Android

Tags: android, android-intent

Estoy intentando comunicar entre dos aplicaciones en android con android studio para ello en una tengo un botón el cual pulso y abro la otra app. Esto funciona bien pero el bundle que tengo que recibir llega null.

```
Bundle userDetails = new Bundle();    
userDetails.putString("key", "value");

 Intent launchIntent = 
 getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.nombrepaquete");
            launchIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            launchIntent.putExtras(userDetails);
            startActivity(launchIntent);
```

Tambien he probado simplemente a enviar

```
launchIntent.putExtra("data" , "data");
```

por probar pero nada, siempre null.

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String data = intent.getStringExtra("data");
    Toast.makeText(this, "b: "+data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

¿Alguien me puede ayudar a recibir un bundle entre dos aplicaciones?

Gracias.

Comment: Conseguido con la respuesta marcada como correcta de este [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45433120/how-to-use-putextra-to-open-another-app-and-send-some-data-for-it)

Answer (score 0):

La forma mas sencilla es mediante peticiones de broodcast desde la app1 y recogerlo desde la app2 hay que tener en cuenta que para que según que tipo de broodcast estaría bien tener securizados los recievers:

**App 1 :**

```
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClassName("com.appstore", "com.appstore.MyBroadcastReceiver");
        intent.setAction("com.appstore.MyBroadcastReceiver");
        intent.putExtra("KeyName","code1id");
        sendBroadcast(intent);
```

**App 2:**

```
Reciver:
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String data = intent.getStringExtra("KeyName");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Data Received from External App" + data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

Manifest :

```
        <receiver
            android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="first_app_packagename" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

MainActivity :

```
  MyBroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver,
                new IntentFilter("first_app_packagename"));
```

Código sacado de [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38608496/how-to-send-data-between-one-application-to-other-application-in-android)

Comment: El código de esa respuesta me parece que no es correcto, en la misma respuesta agregan anotaciones, habría que hacer un ejemplo y agregar que debe implementar código en la app destino para recibir la información.

Comment: @Jorgesys respecto a las anotaciones las básicas para que funcione el código están es posible que falte alguna mejor. Si que faltaba la recogida de datos cuando llega al receiver acabo de añadirlo.

Comment: Hola. Gracias por las respuestas. Estoy probando pero en la aplicación App1 estoy recibiendo un error

android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {package.MyBroadcastReceiver}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Revisa el manifest si has añadido la activity probablemente no estara

Comment: En el manifest simplemente he añadido el <receiver> indicado en la respuesta y un exported=true en la actividad que contiene el <intent>. No se si debo añadir algo mas

Comment: Añade el código completo del manifest y del MainActivity. En esta linea  <receiver
            android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver" no hagas copy paste y haz el autocomplete para asegurar que la ruta es correcta.